# Allure report generation

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Allure reports are generated in .html format instead of .json format.

I am trying to generate allure report with robot framework, but blank report generated.
Follow this link "https://docs.qameta.io/allure/" for all dependency installation.
use this command  "robot --listener allure_robotframework --report allure test.robot" to execute test
scripts. but allure report generated in .html file instead of .json file.
Why?